# Getting command-not-found working under zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh

I'm trying to get the `command-not-found` feature under Ubuntu to work under zsh, without luck:

```
➜  ~  pdfunite
zsh: command not found: pdfunite
➜  ~  bash
u@ub:~$ pdfunite
The program 'pdfunite' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Does anyone know if there is a package available that also supports zsh?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to source it in your .zshrc:

```
if [[ -s '/etc/zsh_command_not_found' ]]; then
  source '/etc/zsh_command_not_found'
fi
```

The script is part of the package *command-not-found*:

```
$ apt-cache search zsh_command_not_found
> command-not-found: /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```