# How to make oh-my-zsh recommend uninstalled packages like bash?

Tags: bash, zsh

I want zsh to recommend packages to install if I insert a command whose package is not installed like in Bash.

Like [image]

Comment: Does this help? [Getting command-not-found working under zsh](http://askubuntu.com/questions/324725/getting-command-not-found-working-under-zsh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your ~/.zshrc

```
source /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```

and run

```
source ~/.zshrc
```